# CORS policy blocks localhost

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, cors

I made some web project using Spring Boot 2 with rest API. I had two projects, the one is rest API, another is web project calling rest API. I already using `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")`. So, It works well in the controller class.

However, when I call request to other controller class, chrome print it to me, `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/signout/1234' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`. How can I solve this problem?

This is my working controller class. There is no other special in blind space:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController {
...
@PutMapping("/users")
public User updateUser(@Valid @RequestBody User updatedUser) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        User savedUser = userRepository.findByUsername(updatedUser.getUsername());
        savedUser.setPassword(updatedUser.getPassword());
        savedUser = userRepository.save(savedUser);
        return savedUser;
    }
...
}
```

This is working ajax:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            ...
        } else if (this.status == 500) {
            alert(this.responseText);
        }
    }

    var json = JSON.stringify(param);
    xmlHttp.open("POST", mainurl+"admin/role", false);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    xmlHttp.send(json);
```

This is not working controller. At first I just used `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*").

```
//@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8081", allowedHeaders = "*")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowCredentials = "true", methods = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.DELETE})
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UserController {
...
}
```

This is not working ajax with JWT.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "DELETE", 
        url: "http://localhost:8080/signout/"+username,
        async: true,
//      crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer '+ "${token}");
        },
        success: function(result, status, xhr){
            //service 표시
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });

//      var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
//      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
//          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
//              location.href=window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/sso_ui/";
//          } else if (this.status == 500) {
//              alert(this.responseText);
//          }
//      }

//      xmlHttp.open("DELETE", "http://localhost:8080/signout/"+username, false);
//      xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
//      xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + "${token}");
//      xmlHttp.send();
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Preflight request is OPTIONS request and you haven't listed that one in the allowed methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `OPTIONS` method to the list of allows methods:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowCredentials = "true", methods = {RequestMethod.OPTIONS, RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.DELETE})
```

`OPTIONS` method is being used in [preflight requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS#Preflighted_requests_in_CORS) to identify the list of  acceptable HTTP methods.

Answer (score 1):

*Option 1*:
*Add* *RequestMethod.OPTIONS*

```
 @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowCredentials = "true", methods = {RequestMethod.OPTIONS, RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.DELETE})
```

*Why OPTIONS?*

This pre-flight request (RequestMethod.OPTIONS) is made by some browsers as a safety measure to ensure that the request being done is trusted by the server. Meaning the server understands that the method, origin and headers being sent on the request are safe to act upon.

---

*Option 2*: *WebConfig for CORS*

You can create one WebConfig Class for CORS Origin Configuration so that we ***don't need to write `@CrossOrigin` at each and every controller.***

*WebConfig.java*

```
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements Filter,WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
      HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
      HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
      System.out.println("WebConfig; "+request.getRequestURI());
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With,observe");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "USERID");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "ROLE");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "responseType");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "observe");
      System.out.println("Request Method: "+request.getMethod());
      if (!(request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS"))) {
          try {
              chain.doFilter(req, res);
          } catch(Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      } else {
          System.out.println("Pre-flight");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,DELETE,PUT");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Expose-Headers"+"Authorization, content-type," +
          "USERID"+"ROLE"+
                  "access-control-request-headers,access-control-request-method,accept,origin,authorization,x-requested-with,responseType,observe");
          response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
      }

    }

}
```

Comment: It didn't solve my problem T^T. I tried to apply two options. Option 1 didn't solve my problem. So, I tried option 2. However, it also didn't solve my problem and occurred a new problem (regarding `@PathVariable` parameter). How should I do...?

Comment: Hello @Rect are you still facing the CORS issue or some other issue. you can share more details with error so that i can get more idea

Comment: Hello @Patel Romil, I still facing the same issue. There are no more details in my think.. If you want other information, please tell me. I'll provide your request.

Comment: Hello @Rect you are talking about a new problem with `@PathVariable` so I through some new issue is there `instaed of Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/signout/1234' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status`

Comment: @Rect So is there any issue or error with `@PathVariable` or same `has been blocked by CORS policy:`

Comment: Ah, The new problem occurred in other requests, not `http://localhost:8080/signout/1234`. That was `http://localhost:8080/login/www.ttt.com`. In here, "www.ttt.com" received as "www.ttt" in controller. And, In `http://localhost:8080/signout/1234`, CORS problem occurred.

Comment: @Rect Have you removed `@CrossOrigin` from your controller? if not then remove from all controller and try again

Comment: Of cause, when I apply option2, I removed all `@CrossOrigin` in my controllers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196208/discussion-between-patel-romil-and-rect).