# How to fix 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error using (Angular js+springboot)

Tags: angular, spring-boot

When sending the request from angular service to java Controller I'm facing error

```
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
```

1.http://localhost:8080/fileValidate 403

```
2.Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/fileValidate' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

    # Angular-Service

   1.below is my angular service code.

      createFileValidation(filevalidation: Filevalidation): Observable<any> {
                var service = "http://localhost:8080/fileValidate";
                let body = JSON.stringify(filevalidation);
                let headers = this.createHeader();
                headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS,GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
                headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
                headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
                //  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
                return this.http
                    .post(service, body, { headers: headers })
                    .map((response: Response) => {
                        return response.json(); //blob should be use insted of json
                        //return new Blob([response.blob()], { type: 'text/xml' });
                    });
            }
        }
```

1.Below is my JAVA Controller code.

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080/fileValidate")
public class FileValidationController {
    @Autowired
    private FileValidationService fileService;
    String results = "success";
    @RequestMapping(value = "/fileValidate", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json" })
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> fileService() {
        System.out.println("Controller");
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS,GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
//        .allow("OPTIONS").build();
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(fileService.validatefile(),headers, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
}
```

Below code are the proxy settings

```
{
    "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080",
      "secure": false
    }
  }
```

**Angular package.json**
here i have done proxy setting please see the script

```
{

  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

1. from Postman I'm able to send same request but when I send the same request from the browser I get this error, So my expectation is the request should hit the JAVA controller.

2.Really I need help on this issue , I have tried all the possible solutions I've found

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/56931953/10961238

Answer (score 1):

The request is blocked because localhost:8080 is a different URL then localhost:4200.

You have to understand that the browser is blocking the request and not the web server. It would be possible for the browser to load the resource but it blocks it because of some web standard.

One option would be to use the same port so you get the same URL.

Another option is to allow other URLs/origins.

Therefore your web server has to response with this header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
```

or to allow all origins:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Edit:

You have now tried to add the header but there are mistakes:

1. Don't add the Access-Control-Allow-* headers to your client code. They are sent from the server to the client.
2. In this line

   @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080/fileValidate")

   you are allowing the wrong origin. The origin is http://localhost:4200

If you are still getting the *No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'* error you can analyze network traffic in your browser (F12 in firefox). See if the header is sent and what its value is.

It might also be necessary to set other Access-Control-Allow-* headers but then you will get a different error message.

Comment: i used two option.  1- @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowCredentials = "true", methods = {RequestMethod.OPTIONS, RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.DELETE}) ,

Comment: 2.I have created one WebConfig Class for CORS Origin Configuration,  But the result is same error i'm getting

Answer (score 0):

When you're using a Spring Boot, why don't you add Filter. Let me give you an example.

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleCORSFilter.class);

    public SimpleCORSFilter() {
        log.info("SimpleCORSFilter init");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

**What are we doing here?**
We are enabling some CORS capability by specific HTTP headers that tell the browser that downloaded webpage should be allowed to make web requests to given/all domains.

You can also restrict HTTP methods(GET/PUT/POST/DELETE etc) on this.

Let me know if you require more information. Happy coding

Comment: **Still facing same error.even i have added filter**

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because your client application and your server application are running in different domains. Browser will make `options` call before making actual API call to check the security.

Even if you add `Access-Control-Allow origin header` in client application header issue won't be solved.

**Server side solution**

You've to enable CORS in your server application using any library or you've to handle `options` call in your back-end application.

Handling `options` call in the sense you've resolve options call with 200 response.

For every API you've to check method and if options method then resolve with 200

**Angular Solution**

Create a proxy.conf.json in the root directory

```
<!-- proxy.conf.json -->
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": true,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

Change the start scripts in package.json

```
<!-- package.json -->
{.
 .
 .
 "scripts": {
        "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
         .
         .
           }
```

Change the base URL of your Angular application API calls to `/api/`

Instead of `ng serve` run `npm start`

On doing above changes there will be no `CORS` issue

**Note:** Your server API end point should be something like this `http:localhost:8000/api/fileValidate`

**Note** In the above I added `/api` to the API end point and I configured the same in the `proxy.conf.json`

Hope it'll solve your issue. Please let me know if you face any difficulty.

Comment: It's not working for me,Still same issue i'm facing

Comment: What you tried? Handling `OPTIONS` call in `spring-boot` or in the `Angular` way. If you tried in Angular and followed all the above configuration then you've to run `npm start`. Also you've to change your API end point from `http://localhost:8000/fileValidate` to `http://localhost:8000/api/fileValidate`

Comment: Now i  used http://localhost:8000/api/fileValidate but still getting same issue,Proxy setting also looks good for proxy i am using "proxy.config.json" and "package.json",I don't understand why the same issue is coming. Angular service sending request to URL"http://localhost:8000/api/fileValidate" and in my controller i have used same URL"http://localhost:8000/api/fileValidate", But request is not hitting my controller